# extract text between two strings with perl style regex (ocaml-re)

Tags: regex, ocaml

I'm trying to extract all the strings passed to a require function out of javascript files with a simple regex.

Example

```
var x = require("./something.js");
var y = require("./else.js");
console.log(other);
require("test.js");
```

Out of this file I want to extract: `["./something.js", "./else.js", "test.js"]`.

I managed to write the following regex: `"require\(\"(.*?)\"\)";`

I'm using `ocaml-re` to compile the perl-style regex and match a string like:

```
let everything = Re.all regex js;

let () = 
  List.iter
    (
      fun group -> 
        let g = Re.Group.all group in
        Array.iter (fun s -> print_endline s) g
    ) everything
```

It prints the following:

```
require("./something.js")
./something.js
require("./else.js")
./else.js
require("test.js")
test.js
```

How do I change the regex to only get the `./something.js, ./else.js, test.js` ?

Comment: Why do you print all the groups with Array.iter ? Group 0 is always the full match. Here, you seem only interested in group 1.

Comment: You're totally right, no idea why I just didn't take the group at index 1...

Answer (score 0):

You could extract only the text in between the citations using this regex: 
 `(?<=require\(\").*?(?=\"\))`

- `(?<=require\(\")` is a positive look-behind for the string **require("**
- `.*?` matches everything but newline lazily (aka with as few characters as possible)
- `(?=\"\)` is a positive look-ahead for the string **")**

Comment: Look ahead/behind are completely unneeded here. OP's regex is actually better than yours.

Comment: OP wants a solution in Ocaml, not Perl.

Answer (score 0):

Group 0 is the whole string, and due to `Array.iter` you are also printing it. You can replace

```
let g = Re.Group.all group in
Array.iter (fun s -> print_endline s) g
```

by

```
match Re.Group.all group with
| [| _ ; s |] -> print_endline s
| _ -> ()
```

(or use a `Array.length` test if you prefer that to pattern matching)